# How to fix the Cairo Dock?

Tags: cairo-dock

I have been trying to replace Unity with Cairo Dock, and I am almost there! The only question I have is *how can I turn off the Cairo Dock Auto Hide, so as to fix it in place no matter what?*

Answer (score 0):

I may be preaching to the converted but here goes:

Right click on Cairo, select Cairo Dock > Configure

On the Configuration>Behaviour tab:

- Visibility: Keep the dock below
- Visibility: Appear on mouseover.
- Behaviour of Taskbar: integrated or separated depending on what you prefer.

Click apply and close.

Click the Applications menu, find Startup Applications.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "Reserve space for the dock" option. It fixes the dock in place, doens't hide it, nor does it interact with open windows.

Right click cairo dock > configure > behavior and select "Reserve space for the dock" as visibility value.

[image]